# Finish Build Trigger only fires when parent build is called manually

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, teamcity, octopus-deploy

I have setup a service hook for teamcity build (A) so that my solution is built when i push to github.

I then have a seperate build (B) configuration with a Finish Build Trigger which does some work when the previous Github triggered build A completes.

The weird thing thing is that the B build is only triggered when i manually click 'run' on the A build.

When the A build is triggered by GH it completes successfully but doesn't fire trigger build B.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'd recommend to submit an issue in our tracker with exact settings of finish build trigger and version you're using.

Comment: The solution I found was to not use github hook. I just use the VCS trigger that checks every 60s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JoséF.Romaniello  i found a better way. set up your service hook to trigger step B. Inside TC set step A to be a snapshot dependency inside step B. leave all the check boxes blank. Then github will trigger the final step which will trigger building the dependencies first.